# Can I use jQuery to easily shift li elements up or down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a menu like this:

```
    <ul id="menu" class="undecorated"> 
        <li id="menuHome"><a href="/">Home</a> </li> 
        <li id="menuAbout"><a href="/Usergroup/About">About</a> </li> 
        <li id="menuArchives"><a href="/Usergroup/Archives">Archives</a> </li> 
        <li id="menuLinks"><a href="/Usergroup/Links">Links</a> </li> 
    </ul>
```

Is there a simple way that I can use jquery to re-order elements?  I'm imagining something like this:

```
$('#menuAbout').moveDown().moveDown()
```

But any other way of achieving this is appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's actually not that hard.  JQuery almost gets you there by itself with the **insertBefore** and **insertAfter** methods.

```
function moveUp($item) {
    $before = $item.prev();
    $item.insertBefore($before);
}

function moveDown($item) {
    $after = $item.next();
    $item.insertAfter($after);
}
```

You could use these like

```
moveDown($('#menuAbout'));
```

and the menuAbout item would move down.

If you wanted to extend jQuery to include these methods, you would write it like this:

```
$.fn.moveUp = function() {
    before = $(this).prev();
    $(this).insertBefore(before);
};

$.fn.moveDown = function() {
    after = $(this).next();
    $(this).insertAfter(after);
};
```

and now you can call the functions like

```
$("#menuAbout").moveDown();
```

Comment: Why do you use $variable for each variable, rather than just variable? Not that it’s invalid syntax — it’s just superfluous.

Comment: True.  But it also reminds me that I'm dealing with a jQuery object versus a regular variable/DOM object.

Answer (score 5):

No native prototypal methods, but you can make one easily:

```
$.fn.moveDown = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if ( next.length ) {
            $(next).after(this);
        } else {
          $(this).parent().append( this );
        }
    })
}

$('#menuAbout').moveDown().moveDown()
```

This uses [jQuery.prototype.after](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after)

Comment: You can implement a moveUp by copying the function and replacing 'after' with 'before' and 'append(this)' with 'prepend(this)'.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `display: flex` on the parent then you can use `order`

```js
function reset()
{
  jQuery("#a").css("order", 10);
  jQuery("#b").css("order", 20);
  jQuery("#c").css("order", 30);
}

function reorder1()
{
  jQuery("#a").css("order", 30);
  jQuery("#b").css("order", 20);
  jQuery("#c").css("order", 10);
}

function reorder2()
{
  jQuery("#a").css("order", 30);
  jQuery("#b").css("order", 10);
  jQuery("#c").css("order", 20);
}
```

```css
#main { display: flex; }
#a { color: red; }
#b { color: blue; }
#c { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="a">Foo</div>
    <div id="b">Bar</div>
    <div id="c">Baz</div>
</div>

<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<button onclick="reorder1()">Reorder 1</button>
<button onclick="reorder2()">Reorder 2</button>
```

Comment: this wasn't a thing when I posted the question but yup! you can now.